# JavaScript forEach() Method work differently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Here is the code:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
//debugger;
console.log(img);
[1, 2].forEach(function (item) {

    console.log(img);

    img.removeAttribute("src")

    console.log(img);

    var img_src = document.createAttribute("src");
    img_src.value = '/test?id=' + item;
    img.setAttributeNode(img_src);

    console.log(img);
});
```

At first I ran it on Chrome and get the result:

```
<img src="/test?id=2">
<img src="/test?id=2">
<img src="/test?id=2">
<img src="/test?id=2">
<img src="/test?id=2">
<img src="/test?id=2">
<img src="/test?id=2">
```

But when I use step into in debugger or run it on Firefox,the result is the same as I thought:

```
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img src="/test?id=1">
<img src="/test?id=1">
<img>
<img src="/test?id=2">
```

Maybe the better way is to put the statement in the forEach function.

Is this a bug in developer tool of Chrome?

Comment: Check the value of outerHTML instead of just logging img it will have the proper html, It might be because the DOM is not having time to update all the correct internals before the next log call

Comment: @PatrickEvans That does not explain why the first `console.log(img)` call logs `<img src="/test?id=2">` before reaching `.forEach()` at Chromium 60.

Comment: @guest271314, it might since the forEach iterations is going to tie up the UI and could depending on their code not have taken a text representation of img at the time of console.log() call, and only does so after the loop has completed

Comment: @PatrickEvans Interesting. Not certain which portion of a specification describes what should occur in the current case, if the case is addressed at all in any specification? `DOM`? Browser JavaScript implementation code? Do you get same results at Chromium or Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Interesting... In Chrome, if you wrap the setting of the src attribute in a setTimeout, and delay it by 5ms (edit: this is highly variable apparently), it catches the changes of the src, though not in the sequence of the console logs. Chrome just isn't logging to the console synchronously in this case.

Comment: @guest271314 I don't think it would be in a spec as I am thinking it would be dealing with how the browser interacts with its dev tools window, ie creating a race condition. And since that is wholly a browser thing no agreed upon spec (at least as far as i know). I do get different results in Firefox. But get same results in both browsers when logging outerHTML instead of the image object itself

Comment: Chrome appears to be using a reference to the element, and only resolving the reference after the script has executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think console.log is acting async on Firefox.
It is not standardized, so the behavior might change depending on the version or the browser, it has some async issues probably related to marshaling data across process boundaries.

If you console.log a simple object and then immediately change something in the object, the console.log() does not always show the value.

Try to put `img` in a string, that is immutable and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered one more interesting thing. If you refresh (cmd + r) page with closed console in Firefox you'll get the same result as you have in Chrome. Just open console after refresh ;)

So it looks like a Firefox bug